# Call a photo intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having a problem when I try to call the Camera Intent and make it return the URI of the photo i took and save it in the Sqlite database.

I always get the following log:

```
06-06 13:06:35.195  19091-19091/com.example.eduardo.voiceblog_beta >E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main    Process: com.example.eduardo.voiceblog_beta, PID: 19091    java.lang.NullPointerException: file
           at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:447)
           at camera.Util.getOutputMediaFileUri(Util.java:21)
           at >com.example.eduardo.voiceblog_beta.ConfirmaFoto$1.onClick(ConfirmaFoto.ja>va:64)
           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.jav>a:901)
           at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Here is my Util class:

```
package camera;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by eduardo on 31/05/15.
 * Classe onde defino caminho onde as fotos serão armazenadas
 */

public class Util {

public static final int TIPO_IMAGEM = 1;
public static String localFoto;

public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri (int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/*public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri (int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}*/

public static File getOutputMediaFile (int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "TesteCamera");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;

    if (type == TIPO_IMAGEM) {
        localFoto = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}
}
```

Here is the class where i call the photo Intent:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import BD.Postagem;
import BD.PostagemDAO;
import camera.Util;


public class ConfirmaFoto extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnProximo;
    private PostagemDAO bd;
    private static final int TIPO_IMAGEM = 1;
    String uriFoto;
    private Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirma_foto);

    btnProximo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmaFoto);

    btnProximo.setOnClickListener(proximo);

    bd = new PostagemDAO(this);

    bd.abrir();
    }

    View.OnClickListener proximo = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent principal = new Intent(ConfirmaFoto.this, MainActivity.class);

        String tit = getIntent().getExtras().getString("titulo",null);
        String com = getIntent().getExtras().getString("comentario",null);

        Postagem postagem = new Postagem();
        postagem.setTituloPostagem(tit);
        postagem.setComentarioPostagem(com);

        Date dataAtual = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String data = formataData.format(dataAtual);
        postagem.setDataPostagem(data);
        postagem.setExtra("FIXO");


        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = Util.getOutputMediaFileUri(Util.TIPO_IMAGEM);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


        postagem.setCaminhoFoto(uriFoto);

        bd.criarPostagem(postagem);
        bd.fechar();

        startActivity(principal);

    }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            uriFoto =  Util.getOutputMediaFileUri(Util.TIPO_IMAGEM).toString();
            /*Bitmap vt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Util.localFoto);
            vt = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(vt, 480, 600, false);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vt, 0, 0, 480, 600,matrix, true);
            img.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);*/
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        } else {

        }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_confirma_foto, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

you need to add this the permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```